# How change modal width in react navigation?

Tags: react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v6

I have this setup.
Stack navigator with presentation mode "modal".

[image]

```
            <Stack.Screen
                name="YourOrderDetails"
                options={{ 
                    title: "Order #687557 details",
                    presentation: 'modal',
                    contentStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: '#fff',
                    }
                }}
                component={YourOrderDetails}
            />
```

Sometimes I want to change modal width to make it a little wider.
The documentation does not specify how to do this.
Is there any solution for this?
How i can do that?